# A word for all states of "water"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word used specifically to refer to all states of water (liquid, solid and gaseous)? Obviously, "water" would technically refer to all of them, but most people would interpret "water" as the water in liquid state.

Comment: Go chemical: H2O

Comment: If you mean the point at which water _is_ all stages, you want __triple point__. Otherwise, you could always define it, just as you did in your question.

Comment: or you could go with "water molecules" (i.e can be found in four states of matter )

Comment: If you like having no one understand you: try Hydrogen Hydroxide, Hydronium Hydroxide, or Dihydrogen Monoxide (DMHO).  Otherwise, *context is everything.*  "May I have some water, please" == The speaker wants liquid water in a drinking glass.  "This new exoplanet is 56% water." == Could be solid, liquid, or gas.

Comment: @cobaltduck - Gasp!!  You're recommending that people drink a *chemical* like dihydrogen monoxide???  Do you realize how many people are killed every year from inhaling dihyrogen monoxide?  It's a very dangerous chemical!

Comment: You wrote "states of water" - if water wasn't the answer you couldn't have said this!

Answer (score 0):

***aqua***

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aqua#Noun):

> **aqua** ‎(countable and uncountable, plural aquas or aquae)
>
> (inorganic chemistry) The compound water.

Comment: No. 'Aqua' is far more restricted in its distribution than 'water'.

Comment: "Aqua" is more likely to be considered a type of light blue color than water itself...unless you're speaking Latin.

Answer (score -2):

I think the answer is "Matter". I learnt science in primary school. I remember that there are three states of matter: Liquid, Gas and Solid.

Comment: Yes, but the question is specifically asking about one type of matter, that is, water.